# Adding recipients in list by uploading .csv file in sendgrid api

Tags: php, sendgrid

Hi I am using **Sendgrid Marketing Emails API** for sending bulk of emails. I have a list containing user's email address and Name,now I need to add those emails to my list. I have found one way that is first I'll read the .csv file, get the required columns(e-mail) and store it into an array, then pass that array into the `data` field. 
In vertical response api, they have function called  `appendFileToList` to directly read the data from .csv file and storing it in the list. Is there any function like that in **sendgrid api**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. You can upload a CSV via the UI, or follow your plan to upload via API. Make sure that you're submitting all the fields & only the fields that exist in the list you're appending to, to avoid any errors.